# major-mode as argument to string-match vs string-equal

Tags: string, symbols

**Why** is `(string-match "lisp" major-mode)` not working, while `(string-equal "lisp-interaction-mode"  major-mode)` is working?

`string-match` results in debugger message: `(wrong-type-argument stringp lisp-interaction-mode)`

But help states:

```
(string-equal S1 S2)

(string-match REGEXP STRING &optional START)
```

(`S1` and `S2` is a placeholder for `STRING`, right?)

*I already know that `(string-match "lisp" (prin1-to-string major-mode))` can be used to get the expected result.*

Comment: `(string-match "lisp" (symbol-name major-mode))` would be more precise, depending on what you want `(derived-mode-p 'emacs-lisp-mode)` might make sense.

Comment: In addition, if you only want to check *whether* a pattern matches a string, so you don't care what the matched part is, then consider using `string-match-p` instead of `string-match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string-match` doesn't allow symbols but `string-equal` does.

> (string-equal S1 S2)
>
> Return t if two strings have identical contents.
>   Case is significant, but text properties are ignored.
>   **Symbols are also allowed; their print names are used instead.**

Note that result of evaluating `major-mode` is not a string.